# MySQL loop over table rows, run another query, join results

Tags: mysql, list, loops, subquery, self-join

I have a table `my_table` like (and the NAME column values are unique):

```
ID   NAME   RANK   AGE
1    John   4      21
2    Sam    1      43
3    Tom    3      57
4    Bob    2      39
5    Dave   5      25
```

I want to run a single query where for every row I select all the attributes plus another column that is a list of other names sorted by age DESC and NOT itself with a LIMIT (let's say 3), with the results something like:

```
NAME   RANK   AGE   SOME_LIST
John   4      21    Tom,Sam,Bob
Sam    1      43    Tom,Bob,Dave
Tom    3      57    Sam,Bob,Dave
Bob    2      39    Tom,Sam,Dave
Dave   5      25    Tom,Sam,Bob
```

So the query to just get `SOME_LIST` for John would be something like:

```
SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE name <> 'John' ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 3;
```

and the result would look like:

```
NAME
Tom
Sam
Bob
```

I'm not sure 1) how to get these results into a single column comma-separated and 2) how to run this query for every row in `my_table`.

**UPDATE:**

Getting closer with this query:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM my_table t1 WHERE t1.name <> t2.name ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 3) AS some_list FROM my_table t2;
```

But the `some_list` column does not respect the age desc order by and also does not respect the limit. Only the `<>` is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT m1.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(m2.name ORDER BY m2.age DESC), ',', 3) AS 'SOME_LIST'
FROM my_table m1 LEFT JOIN my_table m2 ON m1.name <> m2.name
GROUP BY m1.ID
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b56945/38/0

To get a comma-seperated list of the names you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY age DESC), ',', 3) AS 'SOME_LIST' 
FROM my_table 
WHERE name <> 'John';
```

With the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` you can limit the number of comma-seperated values. You can also `ORDER BY` the values directly on the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.